# Gridview with checkboxes exported to Excel hangs for extended periods when opening

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview, checkbox

I'm in the process of troubleshooting an issue with a Gridview heavy with checkboxes exported to Excel (Sample code below.  Actual code includes more checkboxes).  What happens is that 1) the user clicks the button to begin the export process, then 2) the user either saves or downloads the file to their desktop, 3) the file takes a considerable amount of time to render the basic cells (> 15 seconds), then once the basic excel file renders 3) the spreadsheet renders the checkboxes (render time takes anywhere from 3 to 10 minutes depending on the speed of the computer) and appears to hang until the checkboxes appear like they appear in the GridView.

I should also note that this sample file is around 800k and I have been able to export other larger gridviews to Excel without the checkboxes almost instantly.

I get that the actual exported file from the web page isn't true a Excel file until you save it as a spereadsheet/workbook.  However, this seems a bit odd that a gridview with checkboxes takes so long to render as a 'spreadsheet'.

My question is this - Is this normal behavior for exporting excel spreadsheets heavy with checkboxes or is there some way I can improve the code below to ensure that the Excel spreadsheet doesn't hang for extended periods when opening?  Is there any other solution that can help speed the checkbox render time?

aspx code

```
<%@ Page Title="Test Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" EnableEventValidation="false" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="form2.aspx.cs" Inherits="form2" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server"></asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" Runat="Server"></asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="38px"  OnClick="Button1_CLick" Text="Export to Excel" Width="200px" />
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Field 1" HeaderText="Field 1" SortExpression="Field 1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Field 2" HeaderText="Field 2" SortExpression="Field 2" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Field 3" HeaderText="Field 3" SortExpression="Field 3" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Field 4" HeaderText="Field 4" SortExpression="Field 4" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Field 5" HeaderText="Field 5" SortExpression="Field 5" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Field 6" HeaderText="Field 6" SortExpression="Field 6" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Field 7" HeaderText="Field 7" SortExpression="Field 7" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Field 8" HeaderText="Field 8" SortExpression="Field 8" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Field 9" HeaderText="Field 9" SortExpression="Field 9" />
      <asp:Panel ID="pnlClick" runat="server" CssClass="collapsiblepanelCSS">
          <div style="background-color:blue;height:30px; vertical-align: middle">
              <div style="float: left;color:white;padding: 5px 5px 0 0 ">
                  Server List Collapsable Panel
              </div>
              <div style="float: right; color: white; padding: 5px 5px 0 0" id="divshow">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="Label" />
                  </div>
              <div style="clear:both">
            </div>
                </div>
              </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlCollapsable" runat="server" Height="0" CssClass="collapsiblepanelCSS">
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Check Box 1" HeaderText="Check Box 1" SortExpression="Check Box 1" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Check Box 2" HeaderText="Check Box 2" SortExpression="Check Box 2" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Check Box 3" HeaderText="Check Box 3" SortExpression="Check Box 3" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Check Box 4" HeaderText="Check Box 4" SortExpression="Check Box 4" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Check Box 5" HeaderText="Check Box 5" SortExpression="Check Box 5" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Check Box 6" HeaderText="Check Box 6" SortExpression="Check Box 6" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Check Box 7" HeaderText="Check Box 7" SortExpression="Check Box 7" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Check Box 8" HeaderText="Check Box 8" SortExpression="Check Box 8" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Check Box 9" HeaderText="Check Box 9" SortExpression="Check Box 9" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Check Box 10" HeaderText="Check Box 10" SortExpression="Check Box 10" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Check Box 11" HeaderText="Check Box 11" SortExpression="Check Box 11" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Check Box 12" HeaderText="Check Box 12" SortExpression="Check Box 12" />
          </asp:Panel>
        <CC1:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="CollapsiblePanelExtender1" Collapsed="true" ExpandControlID="pnlClick" TextLabelID="lblMessage" CollapsedText="Click To Show" ExpandedText="Click To Hide" ImageControlID="imgArrows" ExpandDirection="Vertical" TargetControlID="pnlCollapsable" ScrollContents="false" runat="server"></CC1:CollapsiblePanelExtender>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Field 10" HeaderText="Field 10" SortExpression="Field 10" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Field 11" HeaderText="Field 11" SortExpression="Field 11" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Field 12" HeaderText="Field 12" SortExpression="Field 12" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>

<sql connection strings, insert/update SQL code, update parameters, and closing ASP/HTML tags>
```

cs file

```
   using System;
   using System.Configuration;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.UI;
   using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

   public partial class form2 : system.Web.UI.Page
   {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              Response.Clear();
              Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachement;filename=FileNAme.xls");
              Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xlsx";
              System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
              System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
              GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
              Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
              Response.End();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I determined that with the large amount(s) of checkboxes that are exported to Excel from a gridview (especially when the gridview is of considerable size) it will take the export process quite some time for all of the checkboxes to render correctly to a final product.

Granted, the exported Excel document isn't a true spreadsheet until it is specifically saved as a spreadsheet.  I just wanted to put this on 'record' that the checkbox rendering process takes a considerable amount of time when exported.  Perhaps this could be worked on to make the process not so lengthy in future versions of the products noted in the tags.